# How to put an arrow below a vector?

Tags: math-mode, arrows

I am having trouble writing this vector:

```
$\textbf{v}=(2n-1,n-1,n-1,\ldots,n-1,1,1,\ldots,1)$.
```

I want to indicate that `$n-1$` appears `$n-1$` times and `$1$` appears `$n$` times by writing arrow under `$\ldots$`.

But I can't do it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It should be `\mathbf`, not `\textbf`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually would not use arrows for the job at hand. I suggest, instead, that you use `\underbrace` directives (provided by the `amsmath` package) to provide a platform for the two explanatory text snippets `$n-1$ times` and `$n$ times`. Indicating explicitly that `\mathbf{v}` is a `2n\times1` vector might be helpful too.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \underbrace macro
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{v}^{}_{2n\times1}=(2n-1,\underbrace{n-1,\dots,n-1}_{\text{$n-1$ times}},\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{\text{$n$ times}}\,)'$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is so much better. In the original, for example, you do not know if the number of "1" is "n" or if the arrow substitutes for "n", leading to "n+4" ones...

Comment: This is excellent!

Answer (score 4):

The `amsmath` package provides `\underrightarrow` and `\underset` for this job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{v}=(2n-1,n-1,n-1,\underset{n-1}{\underrightarrow{\ldots}},n-1,1,1,\underset{n}{\underrightarrow{\ldots}},1)$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about shifting the arrow a bit lower?

Comment: @CarLaTeX That's unfortunately [hardcoded in `amsmath.sty`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/65901cc89f241a5100f9ab8685df9b62f92b246f/required/amsmath/amsmath.dtx#L2190-L2192).

Comment: @HenriMenke - The arrows can be shifted down a bit by replacing `\ldots` with `\ldots\mathstrut`.

Comment: You may also want to replace `\underset{n-1}` with `\underset{\mathclap{n-1}}`. `\mathclap` requires the `mathtools package, a fact I'm sure you're aware of too. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have two proposals. In the first one, the arrow reaches a bit beyond the commas, in the second one the arrow covers all objects to be replicated.

The top line is meant to show that the spacing is the same.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\replA}[2]{% #1 = number of times, #2 = object
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip\m@th
    \sbox\z@{$,\dotsc,{}$}%
    \ialign{&\hfil##\hfil\cr
      $#2$&$,\dotsc,{}$&$#2$\cr
      \noalign{\kern 1.5pt}
      &\scriptsize\makebox[\wd\z@]{\hspace{-0.3em}\rightarrowfill\hspace{-0.3em}}\cr
      \multispan{3}\hfil\scriptsize$\mathstrut#1$\hfil\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\replB}[2]{% #1 = number of times, #2 = object
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      $#2,\dots,#2$\cr
      \noalign{\kern 1.5pt}
      \scriptsize\,\rightarrowfill\,\cr
      \scriptsize$\mathstrut#1$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\mathbf{v}=(2n-1,n-1,\dots,n-1,1,\dots,1)$

$\mathbf{v}=(2n-1,\replA{n-1}{n-1},\replA{n}{1})$

$\mathbf{v}=(2n-1,\replB{n-1}{n-1},\replB{n}{1})$

\end{document}
```

[image]